# Trying to use cleanup function in useEffect hook to cleanup img.onload

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I recently built a React component (called ItemIndexItem) which displays images on my application. For example, I have a Search component which will show an index of filtered Items. Each Item displayed is an ItemIndexItem component. Clicking an ItemIndexItem sends you to a ItemShow page where the same ItemIndexItem is employed.

**Search.jsx**

```
render() {
  return (
    <ul>
      <li key={item.id}>
        <div>
          <Link to={`/items/${item.id}`}>
            <ItemIndexItem src={item.photos[0].photoUrl} />
            <p>${item.price}</p>
          </Link>
        </div>
      </li>
      ...more li's
    </ul>
  )
}
```

**ItemIndexItem.jsx**

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function ItemIndexItem(props) {
  const [imageIsReady, setImageIsReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = props.src;

    img.onload = () => {
      setImageIsReady(true);
    };
  });

  if (!imageIsReady) return null;

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={props.src} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

The component is working exactly as desired, except for a memory leak error thrown in console:

> Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.
>
> in ItemIndexItem (created by ItemShow)
>
> in div (created by ItemShow)

For reference, this is the code inside ItemShow where I render the ItemIndexItem:

**ItemShow.jsx**

```
return (
 ...
   <div>
     <ul>
       {this.props.item.photos.map(photo => {
         return (
           <li key={photo.photoUrl}>
             <div>
               <ItemIndexItem type='show' src={photo.photoUrl} />
             </div>
           </li>
         );
       })}
     </ul>
   </div>
 ...
```

I've tried utilizing a useEffect return function to set `img` to null:

```
return () => img = null;
```

This does nothing, however. Since I don't create a subscription, there's not one to delete. So I think the problem is in the asynchronous nature of `.onload`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're setting the state of a component which isn't mounted anymore. You could use the `useRef` hook to determine if your component is still mounted or not, so for example:

```
function useIsMounted() {
  const isMounted = React.useRef(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  return isMounted;
}
```

and in your `ItemIndexItem`...

```
export default function ItemIndexItem(props) {
  const isMounted = useIsMounted();
  const [imageIsReady, setImageIsReady] = useState(false);

  ...
  img.onload = () => {
    if (isMounted.current) {
      setImageIsReady(true);
    }
  ...
}
```

As described in the React documentation of [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref).

> useRef returns a mutable ref object whose .current property is initialized to the passed argument (initialValue). The returned object will persist for the full lifetime of the component.

This means that you can use it to create references to HTML elements, but you can also place other variables inside of that ref, such as a boolean. In the case of my 'useIsMounted' hook, it sets it as mounted upon initialization, and sets it as unmounted when unmounting.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting a state of a component no longer in the tree.  I have a little hook utility to help with this scenario:

```
import { useCallback, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export const useIfMounted = () => {
  const isMounted = useRef(true)
  useEffect(
    () => () => {
      isMounted.current = false
    }, [])

  const ifMounted = useCallback(
    func => {
      if (isMounted.current && func) {
        func()
      } else {
        console.log('not mounted, not doing anything')
      }
    },[])

  return ifMounted
}

export default useIfMounted
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
    const ifMounted = useIfMounted()

    //other code

    img.onload = () => {
      ifMounted(() => setImageIsReady(true))
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Although there are already two working answers to this question, I would like to give a third (hopefully simpler) one:

You don't need another `useRef` or `useIfMounted` hook -- all you need is a local variable to keep track if the effect is still active and your effect should return a cleanup function, which sets this variable to `false`.

Furthermore, your effect should depend on `[props.src]` and not on `[]`, because if `props.src` changes you probably want to wait for the new image:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function ItemIndexItem(props) {
  const [imageIsReady, setImageIsReady] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (imageIsReady) {
      // Oh, oh, props.src changed ...
      setImageIsReady(false);
    }
    let effectActive = true;
    let img = new Image();
    img.src = props.src;
    img.onload = () => {
      // Only call setImageIsReady if the effect is still active!
      if (effectActive) {
        setImageIsReady(true);
      }
    };
    // The cleanup function below will be called,
    // when either the ItemIndexItem component is
    // unmounted or when props.src changes ...
    return () => { effectActive = false; }
  });

  if (!imageIsReady) return null;

  return (
    <div>
      <img src={props.src} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar problem, I solved it using this.

```
useEffect(() => {
      let img = new Image()
      //only continue if img is not null
      if (img)
        img.onload = () => {
          setHeight(img.height)
          setWidth(img.width)
          img.src = src
        }
    }, [src])
```